# How to find the eigenvalues of this matrix in a simple way?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can anyone help how to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix in a simple way? I expand the characteristic polynomial being,
$$
    \lambda(\lambda-3)(\lambda - 2k) = 0
$$
and get the answer but intuition is that there must be a simple way to find it.
$$
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 + k & 1 & 1 - k \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 - k & 1 & 1 + k \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Your (standard) way seems simple enough.  Find the eigenvalues (which are very easily read off in this case), and then the corresponding eigenvector for each.

Comment: Only my result seems simple enough, but I've gone though all the messy polynomial and simplified to this. the only eigenvalue for me to detect by sight is 0, as it is singular. but what about other two?

Comment: Mary.  Look at your characteristic equation.  Don't you see that the other two eigenvalues are $\lambda = 3$ and $\lambda = 2k$?

Comment: Yes, from the polynomial I can. point is I don't think one needs to go through the determinant and expanding the polynomial for this matrix but at a glance should be able to tell the eigenvalues. But I can only see $\lambda_1 = 0$, $\lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 3 + 2k$

Comment: Mary:  Why do you get only the summation $\lambda_2 + \lambda_3$?  Your characteristic equation factors into three terms.  If any one of them is zero your equation is solved.  Very straightforward.

Comment: Since the matric depends on $k$, one might first have a *quick* glance at what happens with special values of $k$. Well, for $k=0$, we arrive at the all-1-matrix with eigenvalues $0$ and $3$ and obvious eigenvectors. Then one quickly verifies that the eigenvector for eigenvalue $3$ works also with general $k$. (With the two-dimensional eigenspace for eigenvalue $0$, we have a bit less luck)

Answer (score 3):

All three rows sum to 3.  That means $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 3.

$(1,0,-1)$ looks to also be an eigenvector.  The eigevalue for this one is $2k.$

And the sum of the eigenvalues equals the trace of the matrix.  (And the product equals the determinant, but that is what we are trying to avoid calculating.)

$0$ is the 3rd eigenvalue.  We could have figured this out as well by the fact that the rows are linearly dependent.

This method is not, in general, a good way to find eigenvalues, but works in special situations.

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at the matrix might suggest cancelling $k$:

Multiply your matrix by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & y & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}^T + y\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$.

Setting $y = -2$ gives $0$ as an eigenvalue and $y = 1$ gives $3$ as an eigenvalue. (Find these values for $y$ either by inspection or solving $(2+y)y = 2 + y$.)

Now the trace constraint gives the last eigenvalue.